# How to increase or decrease values continuously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When mouse click and hold in the element plus, i want to increase or decrease the values, it is working but don't work on mouse hold

```js
var salainv = document.getElementById("sala").value;
var bodegainv = document.getElementById("bodega").value;

function incrementar() {
  document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv++;
  document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv--;
}

function decrementar() {
  document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv--;
  document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv++;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bodega" id="bodega" value="15">
<input type="number" name="sala" id="sala" value="5">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/00/21/plus-31216_960_720.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="incrementar()">
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/minus-clipart-RTA7dagTL.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="decrementar()">
```

Can somebody help me to make it work when mouse is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use onmousedown

Comment: yes but how can I make that work?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) as demonstrated below along with `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events

```js
var salainv = document.getElementById("sala").value;
var bodegainv   = document.getElementById("bodega").value;

var timerId;
function incrementar() {
      document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv++;    
      document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv--; 
 }
 function beginIncrementar(){
     timerId = setInterval(incrementar,200);
 }
 function endIncrementar(){
     clearInterval(timerId)
 }
 function decrementar() {
      document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv--;
      document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv++; 
 }
 
 function beginDecrementar(){
     timerId = setInterval(decrementar,200);
 }
 function endDecrementar(){
     clearInterval(timerId)
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bodega" id="bodega" value="15">
<input type="number" name="sala" id="sala" value="5">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/00/21/plus-31216_960_720.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="incrementar()" onMouseDown="beginIncrementar()" onMouseUp="endIncrementar()">
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/minus-clipart-RTA7dagTL.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="decrementar()" onMouseDown="beginDecrementar()" onMouseUp="endDecrementar()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and [clearInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) 
on `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`events. Check below example.

```js
var salainv = document.getElementById("sala").value;
var bodegainv = document.getElementById("bodega").value;
var timer;

function incrementar() {
  document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv++;
  document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv--;
}

function decrementar() {
  document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv--;
  document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv++;
}

function mouseDown(v) {
  if (v == 'inc')
    timer = setInterval(incrementar, 100);
  else
    timer = setInterval(decrementar, 100);
}

function mouseUp(v) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bodega" id="bodega" value="15">
<input type="number" name="sala" id="sala" value="5">

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/00/21/plus-31216_960_720.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="incrementar()" onmousedown="mouseDown('inc')" onmouseup="mouseUp('inc')">
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/minus-clipart-RTA7dagTL.png" style="width: 40px;" onClick="decrementar()" onmousedown="mouseDown('dec')" onmouseup="mouseUp('dec')">
```

Comment: @DownVoter - Can you mention why was this answer down voted ?

Comment: I dont know (it wasnt me) but maybe because you came in 15 minutes later and just posted the same answer as me. People often see this as an attempt to artificially bump rep (ie, find a good answer and just copy it to try to get rep)

Comment: @Jamiec : Thanks for reply. I coded this solution, but didn't noticed your answer while posting. I thought my answer would minimize 2 functions and so i didn't deleted it

Answer (score 0):

To be more reliable about @Jamiec's answer, I also added **onMouseOut** because when you start mouseDown (without any mouseUp) and move your mouse out of the trigger, the incrementar or decerementar won't stop anymore:

```js
var salainv = document.getElementById("sala").value;
var bodegainv   = document.getElementById("bodega").value;

var timerId;
function incrementar() {
      document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv++;    
      document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv--; 
 }
 function beginIncrementar(){
     timerId = setInterval(incrementar,200);
 }
 function endIncrementar(){
     clearInterval(timerId)
 }
 function decrementar() {
      document.getElementById("sala").value = salainv--;
      document.getElementById("bodega").value = bodegainv++; 
 }
 
 function beginDecrementar(){
     timerId = setInterval(decrementar,200);
 }
 function endDecrementar(){
     clearInterval(timerId)
 }
```

```css
a{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding:10px;
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="bodega" id="bodega" value="15">
<input type="number" name="sala" id="sala" value="5">
<a onMouseOut="endIncrementar()" onClick="incrementar()" onMouseDown="beginIncrementar()" onMouseUp="endIncrementar()">+</a>
<a onMouseOut="endDecrementar()" onClick="decrementar()" onMouseDown="beginDecrementar()" onMouseUp="endDecrementar()">-</a>
```